# append entries in csv in a for loop by using dataframe.to_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am using the below code in a for loop, the problem is whenever a new loop starts, a new csv is formed that means deleting the previous entries. I want that the entries get appended. I can do it using csv write but would be nice to know using pandas.

```
prediction.to_csv("tmp.csv" , sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', doublequote=False, index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with most file operations you can tell them which way you want to open the file with:

Doku: [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Just use the append mode:

```
prediction.to_csv("tmp.csv" , sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', \
    doublequote=False, index=False, mode="a")
```

You might also want to include a

```
useHeader = True
```

before your loop and modify your command to:

```
prediction.to_csv("tmp.csv" , sep='\t', encoding='utf-8', \
    doublequote=False, index=False, mode="a", header = useHeader)
useHeader = False
```

so you only get one header on top of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. :)